# Ruby parser for obj-c

Tags: objective-c, ruby, parsing

I'm trying to write a small ruby gem to generate statistics about my Xcode project.
I have no problem with file numbers, row numbers and so on, but I want also generate statistics about the number of methods, number of classes etc.

There is some kind of obj-c parser written in Ruby?
The alternative can be to interact with OCLint executable but I'm scared it will be a lot of work for a small utility.

Comment: Aren't this links something what you are looking for?https://gist.github.com/postmodern/781559
https://github.com/oggy/cast

Comment: @NickRoz is correct. You could build your own context-free grammar (CFG) for Obj-C. Doing so does seem like overkill since you only want to extract specific metadata. Try regular expressions first, I'd say.

Comment: Agreed with @Sean, in case you want to collect statistics it would be quite easy to write your own regular expressions so as to count occurrences of classes and methods.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of such a publicly-available parser—or grammar for that matter—that represents Obj-C syntax in Ruby.

Here are a couple ways that come to mind to solve your task.

#### Two Options:

1. If you're interested in counting certain metadata about files, you can try making a naive, poor-man's "parser" using regular expressions that extract this metadata.
2. If you're merely interested in the number of methods and such (symbols) of a compiled project, you can use `otool` or `nm` to dump symbols (`nm` will dump global variables as well) of your object (compiled binary).

*Not 100% if these tools work on compiled Swift objects*

---

#### The Commands:

```
otool -TV <object>
nm -a <object>
```